# How to download and install applications with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Prior to April, I was able to run this PS1 script to install Adobe acrobat and zoom. The script was able to check the version on the site (s) and download and install... However, from April to here I have to specify the version (current) in order to download and install... Can anyone help me to have the script check on the current version from the site and download and install...

```
# Download and Install Files
# Will print what it is trying to download and whether it was successful or not with the error code
# [string]$fileName: The name of the file the function is attempting to download and install
# [string]$URI: The full path to the file from where it will be downloaded
# [string]$Arguments: Any installation arguments neccesary
function DownloadInstall($fileName, $URI, $Arguments){
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Downloading $fileName"
    $WebClient.DownloadFile($URI, $fileName)
    $fileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($fileName)
    if($fileExtension -eq ".msi"){
        # I believe this should be $fileName not msiexec.exe
        $InstallProcess = (Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru -Wait)
        # Doesn't wait to know what ExitCode is before performing condition
        $ExitCode = $InstallProcess.ExitCode
        if($ExitCode -ne 0){
            Write-Error "$fileName Installation Failed! `n Error Code: $ExitCode"
            exit $ExitCode
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "$fileName Installed Successfully!"
        }
    }
    if($fileExtension -eq ".exe"){
        $InstallProcess = (Start-Process -FilePath $fileName -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru -Wait)
        $ExitCode = $InstallProcess.ExitCode
        if($ExitCode -ne 0){
            Write-Error "$fileName Installation Failed! `n Error Code: $ExitCode"
            exit $ExitCode
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "$fileName Installed Successfully!"
        }
    }
}

# Check if able to run command (need admin privledge
If (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]'Administrator')) {
    Write-Host "You didn't run this script as an Administrator. This script will self elevate to run as an Administrator and continue."
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ("-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"{0}`"" -f $PSCommandPath) -Verb RunAs
    Exit
}

# Find latest version of file to be downloaded
#$arWeb = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://get.adobe.com/reader/' -UseBasicParsing
$arVersion = "2200120117"
#$arVersion = [regex]::match($arWeb.Content,'Version \d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d').Groups[1].Value.Substring(2).replace('.','')
#$arVersion = [regex]::match($arWeb.Content,'Version ([\d\.]+)').Groups[1].Value.Substring(2).replace('.','')



$zoomWeb = Invoke-WebRequest "https://zoom.us/download" -UseBasicParsing
#$zoomVersion = "5.10.7.6120"
$zoomVersion = [regex]::match($zoomWeb.Content,'\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d\s\(\b\d{1,4}\b)').Value.Trim().replace('(','.').replace(')','').replace(' ', '')



# Program File Names
$arFileName = "AcroRdrDC" + $arVersion + "_en_US.exe"
$zoomFileName = "ZoomInstallerFull.msi"


# URLs for each program to be downloaded
$arURLPrefix = "https://ardownload2.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/$arVersion/"
$zoomURLPrefix = "https://cdn.zoom.us/prod/" + $zoomVersion + "/"


# In case of 64-bit system
if([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem){
    
    $zoomURLPrefix = "https://cdn.zoom.us/prod/" + $zoomVersion + "/x64/"
    $arFileName = "AcroRdrDC" + $arVersion + "_en_US.exe"
    $zoomFileName = "ZoomInstallerFull.msi"
   
}

# Full URI Paths to files for download
$arURI = $arURLPrefix + $arFileName
$zoomURI = $zoomURLPrefix + $zoomFileName


# Specfic Arguments for each download
$arArguments = "/msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES /qn"
$zoomArguments = "/i `"$zoomFileName`" /qn"


# Call Download Command
DownloadInstall $arFileName $arURI $arArguments
DownloadInstall $zoomFileName $zoomURI $zoomArguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex to find the Zoom version needs to be like this:

```
$zoomVersion = [regex]::match($zoomWeb.Content,'\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d\.\d{1,4}').Value.Trim()
```

The Adobe website is not supporting Internet Explorer as a user agent anymore (that is what PowerShell is still using under the hood), so you get a status page with that message, instead of the page with the information to find the latest version.

Comment: Can powershell be force to use edge or another browser?